# StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: Rails migration error for remove Foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am trying to add Foreign Keys to already existing ids in a table and run the migrations as:

```
rails g migration AddForeignKeysRefToQuotes
```

I opened the migration file and added:

```
class AddForeignKeysRefToQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :quotes, :groups,name: "index_quotes_on_group_id"
    add_foreign_key :quotes, :users, column: :created_by_id, name: "index_quotes_on_created_by_id"
    add_foreign_key :quotes, :template, column: :work_template_id, name: "index_quotes_on_work_template_id"
  end
end
```

In the above file, I have added wrong table name for work_template_id, so while running

> rake db:migrate
>   it gave an error, but the remaining columns group_id and created_by_id are created except the third one. I couldn't find the file but I can see Foreign keys in Schema.rb and mysql.

I tried running `rails g migration RemoveForeignKeysRefFromQuotes`
and added the following in remove migrations as:

```
class RemoveForeignKeysReFromQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :quotes, :groups, name: :index_quotes_on_group_id
    remove_foreign_key :quotes, :users, column: :created_by_id, name: :index_quotes_on_created_by_id
  end
end
```

but I am getting error as:

> == 20181024060431 RemoveForeignKeysReFromQuotes: migrating ====================
>   -- remove_foreign_key(:groups) rails aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Table 'groups' has no foreign key for

Please help me out.

Comment: you are trying to remove the `foreign_key` from table `groups`, but if you check in your `psql` database the table `groups` does not have that foreign key. your options are either **edit that migration to add the foreign key**, then comment that `migration`, migrate down, add your `remove_foreign_key` code and `migrate:up`  or run `rails db:reset` and loose all data or manually do sql maintenance in your db

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I am trying to remove Foreign Key & references of groups and users in Quotes table.

Comment: Could it be that you are using `template` singular and not `templates`? `add_foreign_key :quotes, :templates, column: :work_template_id, name: "index_quotes_on_work_template_id"`